# How can I replace values in a list with dictionary values (keys are indices of list to be replaced)?

Tags: python

I think that this should be a relatively simple task, yet I can't seem to figure it out.

```
a = {1: 'the last bus', 2: 'you take', 4: 'train I try', 6: 'see its'}
b = ['I miss', 'nan', 'nan', 'the next', 'nan', 'but you', 'nan', 'hard to explain']
```

desired output:

```
['I miss', 'the last bus', 'you take', 'the next', 'train I try', 'but you', 'see its', 'hard to explain']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written any code?

Answer (score 3):

Just loop over the `dict` and reassign each key in the `list` to the associated value:

```
for i, value in a.items():
    b[i] = value
```

This modifies `b` in place; simplest solution if you want it unmodified is to copy it up front:

```
c = b[:]
for i, value in a.items():
    c[i] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    if i in a.keys(): b[i]= a[i]
```